# How to open Microsoft Office with JavaScript (Chrome, Firefox, IE)

Tags: javascript, excel, internet-explorer, firefox

I want open Microsoft Office products (Word, Excel,..) with JavaSript (like activeXObject). This should be possible with all browsers (Chrome,Firefox, IE).

Usecase: In my browser show list of,if I click on one of the files, they should be open with Microsoft Office product ( Word for Doc , ... ).

Comment: Normally when people click on a link to a file it opens up in the correct application. So what is the problem?

Comment: I invite from the database a list of only the names of the files . When I click on a file , this file is loaded from the database via JavaScript. This should automatically open for example with Word

Comment: Are you setting the correct header for content-type?

Comment: Why header?  I dont need a header, if I loaded a list with the name from the database

Comment: Where is the file coming from? How is it served? Is it a hard coded file on the server or is it a file blob from the database?

Comment: So yes, you need to set the content headers when you server that blob.

Comment: Ok thx and when i have hard coded file on the server?

Comment: do you know for this problem an example?

Answer (score 0):

Set the header of the file's content type when you are spitting out the blob from the database so the application knows what to do with it.

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
```

The header() is whatever method your serverside language uses to set the header.